# How to disable/deactivate a data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have just created a data pipeline and activated it. But while running, it showed *`WAITING_ON_DEPENDENCIES`* for my *`EC2Resource`*. I suspect that this might be due to some permissions issue.

So, I now want to edit the pipeline. But when I open the pipeline, it says "*`Pipeline is active.`*". And many of the fields are not editable anymore. Is there any way to deactive and/or edit the pipeline?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.
The only way that I was able to proceed, was to clone the pipeline into a new one and then edit the new one. All the fields are editable there.  The old one I deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The limitations on editing an active pipeline are [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-manage-pipeline-modify-console.html).

> Before you activate a pipeline, you can make any changes to it. After you activate a pipeline, you can edit the pipeline with the following restrictions. The changes you make apply to new runs of the pipeline objects after you save them and then activate the pipeline again.
>
> - You can't remove an object
> - You can't change the schedule period of an existing object
> - You can't add, delete, or modify reference fields in an existing object
> - You can't reference an existing object in an output field of a new object
> - You can't change the scheduled start date of an object (instead, activate the pipeline with a specific date and time)

Basically, you can't change the schedule or the execution graph. That still leaves a lot of non-"ref" properties you can edit (S3 paths, etc.) Otherwise, you will need to use the Clone-and-Edit trick.

You can also [deactivate a pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-deactivate-pipeline.html) in order to pause the execution schedule, either to edit the pipeline or for something like a DB maintenance window.